# I18n in ReportViewer toolbar

Tags: c#, .net, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I'm using ReportViewer (version 10)in my webpage and I can't firgure out how to change the language of the toolbar. Following is the image of the toolbar that I'm talking about.

[image: Report toolbabr]

Basically, I need to display the text, "Find" and "Next" and tooltips in Portuguese.
I googled a bit and found some possible solutions bit didn't work. One of the was to add

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/>
```

in my web config, but I got the same results, another was to add

```
<%@ Page UICulture="pt-BR" Culture="pt-BR" %>
```

in my page, also didn't work.

My report server is remote, I think that might be the issue, but I couldn't find a way to pass a parameter to the SSRS to set the language.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement the IReportViewerMessages Interface.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254250.aspx

Sample:
http://blogs.infosupport.com/localizing-microsoft-reportviewer/

Hope this helps.